# Looking for right component in my simple diagram

Tags: power-supply, relay, low-power, controller

I am not electical engineer therefore stumbled upon this simple issue. In need to activate a 120VAC 1HP motor from sprinkler timer that has 4 individual channels providing 24VAC up to 400mA voltage each. When each individual channel being activated in sequence it needs to energize the motor as well.

I used 1A 30V diode for each channel to prevent current backflow. 
To activate the motor I thought using relay but most of them at coil have input 24VAC 110mA or below. If I apply 350mA it will burn out the relay coil. 
Please see my diagram. Would appreciate if you can give me simple and working design to my application along parts that I can use.

Thank you for your help!!!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnVHGy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I don't know if I understand you right, but your Sprinkler Outputs are rated as 24V, 400mA? why not use a 24V relay that can switch your 120VAC Motor?

Answer (score 1):

The controller output can provide UP TO 400 mA, but any load will only take the current it requires.  The controller does not force 400 mA through the load.

You can safely use any relay with a 24 volt coil, providing the relay coil draws less than 400 mA.

Comment: Also remember that you need some current for the solenoid valve, the balance of 400mA is available for the relay.

Comment: _'You can safely use any relay with a 24 volt coil'._ His supply is 24 V AC. His diode solution will give him DC. You need to specify AC or DC relay coil.

Comment: Oops - I missed the AC part...  However, my answer re the relay coil only taking the current it requires is still valid, but he requires a 24 VAC relay.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Today I decided to use regular phone charger to run through the sprinkler timer. Negative end I connected directly to 3-32VDC relay coil end, the positive end to 24VAC line that goes to the sprinkler. Hoping that once timer switches on to sprinkler valve it also will activate positive end on the relay coil. I put a diode on timer common/neutral connection and diode on each sprinkler output connection to prevent shorting the lines. Seems it worked in test mode but I have to run it in working condition for few hours. Hope it can work, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f92AUL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The proper way but requires four 24 V AC relays.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl8ABm.png)</sup>

*Figure 1. Single DC relay option.*

Your diode idea could work but you'll have to use a DC relay.

Half-wave rectified AC will give \$ V_{OUT} = \sqrt {2} \cdot V_{RMS}\$ and so for your 24 V you will get about 16 V when the diode drop is taken into account. 16 V relays are rare so you can:

- Use a 12 V relay with a series resistor of 1/3 of the coil value.
- Use a 24 V relay and add some capacitance in parallel with the coil to hold voltage up between half-cycles.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Today I decided to use regular phone charger to run through the sprinkler timer. Negative end I connected directly to 3-32VDC relay coil end, the positive end to 24VAC line that goes to the sprinkler. Hoping that once timer switches on to sprinkler valve it also will activate positive end on the relay coil. I put a diode on timer common/neutral connection and diode on each sprinkler output connection to prevent shorting the lines. Seems it worked in test mode but I have to run it in working condition for few hours. Hope it can work, what do you think?

Comment: Post a schematic in either your original post or in a new answer. The quickest way is to click edit on my post, click 'edit this schematic', select the whole lot and 'copy'. Back out of mine and then enter a new schematic on your post and 'paste' it in. Modify it to reflect what you've done. I don't understand how you've wired up the charger or diodes.

Answer (score 0):

With an AC output on the controller it is probably using a reed relay or similar (eg not solid state) so you probably don't have to protect it with the diode, but if you include the diode in the design remember that it's 24VRMS so the peak is around +-33.5V, and it could also be subject to high voltages from the relay when it's de-energized, so a 30V diode might frazzat the first time you try it.

To keep the de-energizing voltage down you can add a capacitor across the relay coil, or if you go with the diode and DC relays a reverse biased diode across the relay to short out the de-energizing voltage spike.

I would suggest a 24VAC relay with the lowest coil current possible, with a capacitor across the coil(maybe around 10uF, but really depends on the relay. Non-polar), driven directly from the controller.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Today I decided to use regular phone charger to run through the sprinkler timer. Negative end I connected directly to 3-32VDC relay coil end, the positive end to 24VAC line that goes to the sprinkler. Hoping that once timer switches on to sprinkler valve it also will activate positive end on the relay coil. I put a diode on timer common/neutral connection and diode on each sprinkler output connection to prevent shorting the lines. Seems it worked in test mode but I have to run it in working condition for few hours. Hope it can work, what do you think?